# Angular - Slider with scroll

Tags: css, angular, function, events, scroll

I tried to make a slider with scroll, I succeed to do this :

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
scrollEvent(event) {
  console.log('afterScroll:', this.afterScroll, 'pageYOffset:', window.pageYOffset);
  this.afterScroll = window.pageYOffset;
  if (window.pageYOffset > this.scrollTop) {
    // DOWN
    this.getNextProject();
  } else {
    // TOP
    this.getPrevProject();
  }
  this.scrollTop = this.afterScroll;
}
```

Well, I managed to detect the scroll, down and up. But it calls a lot of time the fonction, so it doesn't work really good.

I'd like a style effect when I scroll:
https://www.raoul-gaillard.com/

i wanted to know how to get just one call on this fonction like that it doesn't go crazy.

If you want view the website : http://narty.fr/demo/new/

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: could you provide a live version to test it? like adding it to https://plnkr.co/

Comment: I can not put it online on this site. how i can do?

Comment: This page explains what you might keep in mind to provide a minimal reproduction of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you could create a basic and minimal structure that reproduce your issue, create an micro angular project at plunkr and reproduce your structure

Comment: ok but on this website i have any result when i put my code, i have juste a blank page o,O :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript is impossible to detect end of scroll event. This event will be fire on each pixel travelled.

To prevent this over call. You have to deal with timeout / clearTimeout trick.

```
private timeoutQueue: number;

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
scrollEvent(event) {
    /**
     * If another timeout is on queue who have to be process, let cancel it.
     **/
    if(this.timeoutQueue) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutQueue);
    }

    /**
     We store timeout uniq reference on class property to be able to cancel it if another scroll is fire before execution time of this timeout.
    **/
    this.timeoutQueue = window.setTimeout(() => {

        console.log('afterScroll:', this.afterScroll, 'pageYOffset:', window.pageYOffset);
        this.afterScroll = window.pageYOffset;
        if (window.pageYOffset > this.scrollTop) {
            // DOWN
            this.getNextProject();
        } else {
            // TOP
            this.getPrevProject();
        }
        this.scrollTop = this.afterScroll;

    }, 1000); // I recommand you to keep 1second timeout, is anough smooth to not be detect by user, and anough long to not spam interpreter.
}
```